# AppleScript: renaming PDF with content of PDF

Tags: applescript

I am trying to do exactly what is described in the following thread:
[AppleScript/Automator: renaming PDF with extracted text content of this PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817570/applescript-automator-renaming-pdf-with-extracted-text-content-of-this-pdf/68753373#68753373)

So I am using the Chino22's version and there are two issues with it:
First, instead of the contents of the pdf, theFileContentsText gets some metadata stuff.
Second, althought the script runs to the end, I get the following error for the last step:
error "The variable thisFile is not defined." number -2753 from "thisFile"

So, how do I get the text contents instead, and how do I define thisFile to the current pdf that is being processed in the loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As foo suggests, it's not really the best idea for a script as it isn't getting the text of the document. Do your pdfs even have text in them? For example, can they be searched? If you run 'mdls' in the terminal on one of your pdfs, is there anything in the results that you could use for a filename? Regardless, the error message is a result of an error in the script. Makes me wonder if it was even tested. Find 'thisFile' and change it to 'thesefiles'. It will at least run then.

Comment: Well, it seams to pass that point by replacing thisFile with thesefiles, but now I get the message "Can’t set name of {alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Panos:Desktop:Pros 2:testinvoice.pdf"} to "Invoice /Pages 2 0 R.pdf"."  (I also tried to do it via System Events and the same error came up. There is something useful in the mdls command, but not exactly the way I wanted to go. Nevertheless it is an alternative if there is no other way...

Comment: The issue now is that 'thesefiles' is a list (even if it's just one file). Try adding `item 1 of` before `thesefiles` in the set the name line. Actually, replace the line with `set the name of theFileContents to newPDFname`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect the linked script to work.

Except for document metadata, extracting text content from PDF is notoriously difficult and unreliable, and *not* a road you want to go down if you can possibly avoid it. Adobe’s PDF file format is designed for printing, not for data processing. PDF files contain blocks of Postscript-like page drawing instructions, typically compressed, and while it’s possible for PDFs also to include the original plain text for accessibility use, most PDF generators do not do this so the only way to get the original text is by reconstructing it from those low-level drawing instructions—*not* a trivial job.

AppleScript’s `read` command only reads that raw file data; it does not parse it into drawing instructions, never mind translating those drawing instructions back into plain text. Change a PDF file’s extension to `.txt` and open it in a plain text editor, and you’ll see what I mean. Nasty.

If you need to work with the PDF’s original content (text, images, whatever), your best solution is to get those files *before* they were converted into a PDF.

If you *must* extract content from a PDF file, use an existing tool that knows how to do it.

For instance, if you’re lucky enough to have PDFs that contain XFDF (XML form) or [accessibility](https://www.adobe.com/accessibility/pdf/pdf-accessibility-overview.html) data, there are 3rd-party apps and libraries to extract that content in readable form. I can’t think offhand of any that are AppleScriptable (Adobe Acrobat has only minimal AS support) so you’ll probably need to find one you can run from command line (`do shell script` in AS).

Or, if the PDFs have a consistent visual structure, a 3rd-party library such as Python’s [PDFMiner](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/) (which I’ve used in the past) can identify blocks of characters by position and convert those back into strings with varying degrees of reliability (it has to convert font glyphs back into Unicode characters, guess at which characters are close enough to constitute a word, and where to insert space and return characters between those words). You’ll have to write some Python code to extract the bits you want, so look for [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+pdf+extraction) to get started (or pay someone to write it for you).

But again, if you can possibly avoid having to extract text from PDF, you should. You will save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: The more I look into it the more I arrive to the same conclusions!

But there are 3 more factors to this:

I don't have access to the pre-pdfed files
I kinda have to do this one
I discovered that the extract text tool in automator works on my pdfs, so after all there might be hope this time. Does that help in any way?